# PySimpleGUI - Update table with new values after search, and be able to select new values/print in multiline

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Title says it all - I'm trying to be able to update my table with searched values and be able to select those NEW table updated values, and then print info in MultiLine. However, no matter what I do, it keeps selecting old values even if the table is updated. I've literally tried everything - any help would be appreciated.

I've tried reading the window again (`.read()`), I've tried creating a new variable selected = 0 or 1 if the search function was executed and using `if/elif` statement to check if searched or not, I've tried updating `mfgnumbersall = query`_search which gives an index error obviously. Current code is shown below with comments:

```
while True:

    #Opening the window and reading events from API, read every 20 seconds
    event, values = window.read(timeout=20000)

    if event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        get_databaseinfo()
        get_mfgnumbers()

    # EXITING/CLOSING GUI
    if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    # PART SEARCH BUTTON PRESS
    if event == '-QUERYMFG-':
        querymfgwindow = sg.Window('MFG# Search', layoutquerymfg, background_color='Orange', finalize=True, size=(1000, 600))

        get_mfgnumbers()
        querymfgwindow['-MFGINFO-'].update(values=mfgnumbersall)

        while True:
            event_query_mfg, values_query_mfg = querymfgwindow.read()
            get_mfgnumbers()
            querymfgwindow['-MFGINFO-'].update(values=mfgnumbersall)
            
            # MFG SEARCH FUNCTION
            if event_query_mfg == '-SEARCHMFG-':
                selectrow = 1
                mfg_input = querymfgwindow['-INPUTMFG-'].get()
                description_input = querymfgwindow['-INPUTDESCRIPTION-'].get()
                query_search = []
                
                #for loop to append searched-for items
                for i, valuei in enumerate(mfgnumbersall):
                    query_mfg_description = (f'{mfg_input}' in mfgnumbersall[i][0]) & (f'{description_input}' in mfgnumbersall[i][1])
                    if query_mfg_description:
                        query_search.append(mfgnumbersall[i])
                    else:
                        continue
                    
                    #updating table values
                    querymfgwindow['-MFGINFO-'].update(values=query_search)

            # SELECTING A ROW - NEED TO BE ABLE TO SELECT NEW TABLE VALUES TOO
            if event_query_mfg == '-MFGINFO-':
                selected_row = values_query_mfg['-MFGINFO-']
                if selected_row:
                    index = int(selected_row[0])
                    mfgdatabase = mfgnumbersall[index][0]
                    descriptiondatabase = mfgnumbersall[index][1]
                    querymfgwindow['-MULTILINEMFG-'].update(f"Part MFG#:    {mfgdatabase}\nPart Description:    {descriptiondatabase}\nPart Vendor:   \nOther Info etc..:  ", font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))

            # Closing GUI
            if event_query_mfg == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event_query_mfg == 'Exit':
                break

        querymfgwindow.close()

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot execute your code, also not be able to read and understand the complex code.

Nt to debug your code, do just show about updating table data and selecting rows as following demo code.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']
data1 = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
    ['Harry Truman', 'May 8'],
    ['John F. Kennedy', 'May 29'],
    ['George H. W. Bush', 'June 12'],
]
data2 = [
    ['George W. Bush', 'July 6'],
    ['John Quincy Adams', 'July 11'],
    ['Garrett Walker', 'July 18'],
    ['Bill Clinton', 'August 19'],
    ['Jimmy Carter', 'October 1'],
    ['John Adams', 'October 30'],
    ['Theodore Roosevelt', 'October 27'],
    ['Frank Underwood', 'November 5'],
    ['Woodrow Wilson', 'December 28'],
]

sg.theme('DarkGreen')
layout = [
    [sg.Table(values=data1, headings=headings, auto_size_columns=False, col_widths=[20, 15], expand_x=True, expand_y=True, cols_justification='rl', key='-TABLE-')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Update')],
]
window = sg.Window('The Table Element', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Update':
        window['-TABLE-'].update(values=data2, select_rows=[2, 3, 5])

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Jason! I actually figured it out, it was quite simple - the Table was being updated every time the while loop ran:                                                             while True:
            event_query_mfg, values_query_mfg = querymfgwindow.read()
            get_mfgnumbers()
            querymfgwindow['-MFGINFO-'].update(values=mfgnumbersall)                                     Making the table update after every search. Removing that line did the trick!